# How To Detect A Specific Object In A Bitwise Mask Opencv Python

Tags: python, image-processing, object-detection, opencv

I am trying to detect a object in my image and make a bounding box around it

This is what i am trying to detect :
[image]

Here is the characteristics for your help:

- It will always be black
- It will be either on right or left
- It has to be automatic

This what i have achieved so far :

[image]

This is the code for that :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def nothing(x):
    pass

cv2.namedWindow("Tracking")
cv2.createTrackbar("LH", "Tracking", 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar("LS", "Tracking", 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar("LV", "Tracking", 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar("UH", "Tracking", 255, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar("US", "Tracking", 255, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar("UV", "Tracking", 255, 255, nothing)

while True:
    frame = cv2.imread('resultImages/imgCropped.png')
    img = frame.copy()

    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    l_h = cv2.getTrackbarPos("LH", "Tracking")
    l_s = cv2.getTrackbarPos("LS", "Tracking")
    l_v = cv2.getTrackbarPos("LV", "Tracking")

    u_h = cv2.getTrackbarPos("UH", "Tracking")
    u_s = cv2.getTrackbarPos("US", "Tracking")
    u_v = cv2.getTrackbarPos("UV", "Tracking")

    l_b = np.array([l_h, l_s, l_v])
    u_b = np.array([u_h, u_s, u_v])

    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, l_b, u_b)

    res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask)

    cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
    cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
    cv2.imshow("res", res)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

How can I detect this object?

Comment: We need more informations to answer... Do you need it to be automatic or just in this specific image? Is it always located à the left of your image? Is it always black like this?

Comment: @Panda50 I will edit the answer but now for details here is the information: i) it has to be automatic ii) it will at right or left iii) it will always be black

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really sure of what exactly you are trying to do, however I 'll give my best to reveal some key aspects that may help you ..

1.At first you can apply a course crop of your side images exploiting the hint of the object's location. This would alleviate the presence of other similar objects present in your image. That is:

```
while True:
    frame = cv2.imread('resultImages/imgCropped.png')#this returns a numpy array
    img = frame.copy()

    #define a thresshold let's say 1/4rth of the full image
    width = frame.shape[1]
    thress = int(np.ceil(width/4))
    left= img[:,:thress]#full height,cropped width 
    right = img[:,-thress:]
    #cropped=np.concatenate([left,right])#actually you don't have to merge
```

2.Since you are able to distinct your desired info (black/white), you could try to get the contours of your image using opencv [contour features](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_features/py_contour_features.html#b-rotated-rectangle). You could also give a look at this [tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/14/ball-tracking-with-opencv/). Beside this you could apply various conditions on the retrieved contours so as to filter/strengthen your segmentation.

However in case your detection/segmentation needs to be something more than static, I strongly advise you to turn your focus on machine learning-based algorithms, but considering the fact that your objects of interest are far from ordinary, you will have to apply training using your custom-dataset by fine-tuning existing architectures..

Anyway , good luck!

Comment: This question is a little bit outdated because i have made some progress i have some contours including the contour which has the object in it but the problem now is that there are many other contours which i dont care but are max and min so i cant use these function to sort.Do you have any idea also i have posted the question over here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67435559/how-to-get-a-contour-of-more-less-of-the-expected-area-in-opencv-python)

Comment: You can actually apply these conditions on the x,y values of contours retrieved such that are >thresshold (for instance thresshold=image.shape[1] - img.shape[1]//3), so as to discard all the unwanted right and center contours. I ll give it a try and I will attempt to post on your redirected post..